# Why is this Variable Disappearing?

Tags: php, variables

This should probably have a simple answer I just can't figure out.

Anyway, I have a php document and inside of it I define `<?php $pathprefix = '../'; ?>`

Later in the document I use an `<?php require([somefile.php]); ?>` and inside of somefile.php, I have a line that says `<?php echo($pathprefix); ?>` but the '../' I assigned to $pathprefix never shows up. It acts like the variable was never instantiated. What is my problem?

Comment: Are you neither of the 2 calls are inside functions? That would change the scope

Comment: Please post the source of the 2 files.

Comment: Should work. Really, show us the complete source code.

Comment: Sorry for the very late response, I've been out all Thanksgiving! K Prime you are in fact correct. I had placed the require inside of a function, and I understand now why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really need to see your source code to determine the scope. With what you've provided here's two options:

#### Set in $GLOBALS

file1.php:

```
$GLOBALS['pathprefix']= '../';
```

file2.php:

```
require('file1.php');
print_r($GLOBALS['pathprefix']);
```

#### Use a class

file1.php:

```
class Settings {
 const PATH_PREFIX= '../';
}
```

file2.php:

```
require('file1.php');
print_r(Settings::PATH_PREFIX);
```

#### Understand Scope in PHP

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is out of scope in "somefile.php". You could declare the variable global, ie `global $pathprefix = '../'`. Then in somefile.php put `global $pathprefix;` at the top.

Comment: that is incorrect - the variable is still very much in scope when require/include is used.  It will be out of scope inside of a function, but not just because it's in another file

Comment: I didn't say it was out of scope because it is in another file, I said it IS out of scope in somefile.php, probably because the $pathprefix is being first set in a function or is being called in a function. Either way, making it global might be a nasty solution, but it would work.